# Understanding quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm reading a paper by David Monniaux [An encoding of array verification problems into array-free Horn clauses.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.09092)

Second page Line 10:

"Very often, desirable properties over arrays are universally quantified; e.g. sortedness may be expressed as :

$\forall k1,k2\, k1 < k2 \supset a[k1] \leq a[k2]$

Formulas with universal quantification and linear arithmetic over integers and at least one predicate symbol (a predicate being a function to the Booleans) are so expressive that one can define the execution of a Turing machine as a model to such a formula, whence this class is undecidable. There is, therefore, no general algorithm for checking that such invariants hold, let alone inferring them."

But as far as I can understand universal quantifier at outside should not be a problem. We can always eliminate quantifier if it is the only one (excluding the case where an alternative quantifier is present). Can someone help?

Comment: Can't I just pick an arbitrary variable and substitute in place of k1 and k2 and if my variables are arbitrary I have an effect of doing it for all object in the universe of discourse ?

Comment: @Pushpa The technical transformation you're describing in this case is a special case of [Herbrandization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrandization), the dual of Skolemization. It preserves validity, that is to say, the original statement will be true in all models if and only if the new statement with quantifiers eliminated is true in all models. It doesn't preserve satisfiability as clearly there are models in which the new statement holds and the old statement doesn't. Validity is presumably what you care about, so, yes, you can Herbrandize.

Comment: The example they give is just one example of the class of formulae they are considering which (as far as I can tell) does allow arbitrarily nested quantification. Even for the example you gave, they probably don't intend $<$ and $\leq$ to be uninterpreted predicate symbols, and so they may themselves expand into uses of quantifiers, e.g. $x\leq y$ may mean $\exists z\in\mathbb N.x + z = y$.

Comment: That looks like an answer, @DerekElkins.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @DerekElkins. Understood.